# Unable to inherit constructor, An object reference is required

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, derived-class

Consider:

```
using System;

namespace TuristickaAgencija
{
    public class World
    {
        protected char[] dest;

        public World(char[] dest)
        {
            this.dest = dest;
        }
    }

    class Client : World
    {
        private char[] name;
        private char[] surname;
        private int age;
        private int noCounter;
        private bool hasVehicle;

        public Client(char[] name, char[] surname, int age, int noCounter, bool hasVehicle) : base(dest)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
            this.noCounter = noCounter;
            this.hasVehicle = hasVehicle;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting 2 errors:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'World.dest'

Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Program'

I want all classes to be in the same file.

Comment: You have to pass `dest` as a parameter to the constructor, even if you delegate initialization to the base class. Also might I suggest `string` instead of `char[]`? It's much easier to work with.

Comment: `base(dest: dest)` like this?

Comment: Just add 'char[] dest' like this into public Client(char[] name, char[] surname, int age, int noCounter, bool hasVehicle, char[] dest)

Comment: I changed `char[]` to `string`, the same error appears.

Comment: You have `public Client(char[] name, char[] surname, int age, int noCounter, bool hasVehicle) : base(dest)`.  You can't call `base(dest)` until `dest` is defined.  You could pass `base(name)` for example, or you could add `dest` to the list of parameters for the `World` constructor.  And, as @PatrickRoberts pointed out, you *really* want to understand what the difference between `char[]` and `string` (and understand that you don't want `char[]` here.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. `public Client(string name, string surname, int age, int noCounter, bool hasVehicle, string dest) : base(dest)` this works. Also i've initialized dest in the base class.

Comment: As for the `Missing partial modifier` issue, I've just created a new project and it seems to work there.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what `dest` you are trying to pass the constructor of the base class. You can't pass a reference to a field of an instance that has not yet been instantiated.

You should either add a parameter to `Client` constructor and pass this one to the base constructor:

```
public Client(char[] name, char[] surname, int age, int noCounter, bool hasVehicle,
    char[] dest) : base(dest)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.noCounter = noCounter;
    this.hasVehicle = hasVehicle;
}
```

Or you should pass some default value like for example `null` or an empty array:

```
public Client(char[] name, char[] surname, int age, int noCounter, bool hasVehicle) : base(default)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a valid value in order to initialize dest.
dest is not defined in the csope of constructor yet, you are calling the base ctor and should intialzie it.

you can pass name, or surename or add another param and use it.

As for the partial error probably you have already a Program class defined somewhere else in your code and you cannot declare 2 classes with the same name.

hope this helps.